# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS freeze on reboot/shutdown

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad z570 running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS which is freezing on shutdown.

I tried multiple approaches but was not able to solve this problem.
Any help is very very welcome. I am not able to do any work as I don't want to hard shut down my laptop again and again.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You may want to edit your question to include whether this behaviour was present from the very beginning, or if it started to appear after an upgrade (or possibly even out of a sudden). This could help others facing a similar problem to assess whether your problem and solution applies to them, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLUTION:
I just added noefi into the kernel options and my laptop started shutting down in normal way.

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet noefi"
```